# Bootstrap - Redirects to a section of the page goes past the content

Tags: html, css

Video - https://atproducts.xyz/media/Screen%20recording%202022-11-14%2011.33.21.webm
Code - https://github.com/Alex-Toucan/atproducts.xyz/blob/main/index.html (too big to fit in this post)

Hello, the community of StackOverflow. I have a problem where a redirect to a section of the page goes past said section. I think it is primarily due to padding the body to make the fixed-top navbar work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It could be the header is overlapping the content. If the header is `fixed` or `sticky`, it removes it from the DOM flow. Try adding `padding-top: //height-of-header px` to the element being blocked.

Comment: Now it looks uneven with a lot of unused space. @Sarah

Comment: If you could share snippets of the specific relevant code, it would be easier to help.

Comment: https://atproducts.xyz @Sarah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, I just had to add `scroll-padding-top:56px;` to the `html` tag.